# If Kayne West/Ye ran for President, would he be listed on ballots as Kayne West or Ye?

Tags: united-states, elections, president, hypothetical

It looks like Kayne West is considering running for President. If he runs in 2024 and is included on ballots, will he be listed as "Ye" or "Kayne West"?

Comment: BTW, Kanye, the etymology of which is uncertain.

Answer (score 2):

Each state sets its procedure for declaration of candidacy and the ballot. He would declare his candidacy in Washington under [this law](https://apps.leg.wa.gov/rcw/default.aspx?cite=29A.24.031). He or his proxies would look [here](https://www.sos.wa.gov/elections/candidates/), eventually reading [this guide](https://www2.sos.wa.gov/_assets/elections/deccand_english_2021.pdf). You will note that it instructs that you should

> Print your name exactly as you wish it to appear on the ballot.
> Nicknames are acceptable.

[RCW 29a.24.060](https://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=29A.24.060) clarifies that

> For filing purposes, a candidate may use a nickname by which he or she
> is commonly known as his or her first name, but the last name shall be
> the name under which he or she is registered to vote. No candidate
> may: (1) Use a nickname that denotes present or past occupation,
> including military rank; (2) Use a nickname that denotes the
> candidate's position on issues or political affiliation; (3) Use a
> nickname designed intentionally to mislead voters.

We have a perennial candidate named "Goodspaceguy", who presumably files with his real name but appears on ballots with just his surreal name.

In case he decides to go for a swash graphic rather than a sequence of letters, he would probably have to argue with the Sec'y of State and file a lawsuit because of the technical problems associating a picture with a candidacy